# Laravel get result from query in side query by Eloquent in one object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables:

1. main_presentations
   so here i have "**id**" and "**isEnabled**";
2. child_presentations
   And here i have "**id**" , "**isEnabled**" and "**idParent**";

I want to select in **one object** this is my code:

```php
public function MainSlider(MainPresentation $MainPresentations, ChildPresentation $ChildPresentations)
{
    $MainPresentations = MainPresentation::where('isEnabled', true)->get();
    foreach ($MainPresentations as $MainPresentation) {
        $AnArray[] = ChildPresentation::where([
            ['idParent', $MainPresentation['id']],
            ['isEnabled', true]
        ])->get();
    }

    return $AnArray;

}
```

but this is the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Lhg.png)

Comment: what do you want to do ? Be more clear

Comment: I do not want that ],[  i want one root for JSON array                                           
 CLICK HERE [link](https://image.ibb.co/cQbkDo/jsd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is executing a query per result, which can be ineffective when it starts getting bigger.

You can:

1. Use querybuilder

As it follows, you just build a query starting on ChildPresentation, set a relation to MainPresentation table by id and get the collection

```
public function MainSlider()
{
    $childPresentations = ChildPresentation::join('main_presentations','main_presentations.id','child_presentations.idParent')
    ->where('child_presentations.isEnabled', true)->where('main_presentations.isEnabled', true)->get();

    return $childPresentations;
}
```

If you want all the MainPresentations with their respective ChildPresentations, only the enables ones.

You can take advantage of Laravel relationships and eager loading.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

First, set the relationships in your `MainPresentation` model

In **MainPresentation.php**

```
public function childPresentation {
   return $this->hasMany('App\ChildPresentation', 'idParent', 'id');
}
```

Your **MainSlider function** would be:
(Btw, no idea why you're receiving two arguments if you're overriding them but doesn't matter)

```
public function MainSlider() {
    $mainPresentations = MainPresentation::with(['childPresentations' => function ($advancedWith) { 
       child_presentation.isEnabled is true
       $advancedWith->where('isEnabled', true);
    }])
    ->where('isEnabled', true)->get()->toArray();

    return $mainPresentations;
}
```

This will return an array of MainPresentations that contain an array of child_presentations, with all their childs.

This translates to two queries:

```
Select * from main_presentations where isEnabled = true;
Select * from child_presentations where isEnabled= true and id in (in the first query);
```

Laravel then does background work to create the structure you desire when you write `->toArray()`

Note: If you have a `$visible` array in your **MainPresentation** model, be sure to add: `'childPresentation'` to it, otherwise the toArray will not agregage the childs to the parent.

Second note: I advise following some standards whenever you're writing code, usually functions are named `camelCase` and variables are `camelCase`.

Comment: i have some error:    IMG1 : [link](https://image.ibb.co/iBYtzT/1.png)                             IMG2 [link](https://image.ibb.co/mQXHto/2.png)

Comment: Do you only want the child presentations or you want Main with Child?

Comment: I've added another solution, one is a simple query and the other is with relationships and eager loading. @JustLearnCode

Comment: So good idea thanks but i have Trouble's Here:                                                                                [link](https://image.ibb.co/i2CveT/1.png)             [link](https://image.ibb.co/kLKxto/2.png)                [link](https://image.ibb.co/eBUK68/3.png)

Comment: Please, you need some naming conventions, it gets really confusing reading the code. It is giving the error because for every MainPresentation, you have MULTIPLE childpresentations. Check this https://gyazo.com/bb4c9cc1071f72d56a35da75c724ce1d

Comment: Dear Jonas Staudenmeir,  ###############################

I really appreciate your understanding and support . ###############################


I feel that these changes are going to streamline the current project, and facilitate the organization of those in the future. ###############################


Thank you for your confidence in me. I'm sure you're going to be pleased with the results. ###############################


Best regards, ###############################


Your JustLearnCode ##############################